# Ms access dlookup function error

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

A small question but this is irritating me from 3 hours i tried to use the Dlookup Function in ms access.

I have two subforms in main form in and i tried to get some values from the 1st sub form to the second sub form This gave me a #error but i gave a correct syntax.

I just checked it with a small input and what ever i gave in the form whether it may be a small dlookup command also its giving me the same error.

Confused about whats happening in the forms and please look at the sample dllok up syntax i gave in my forms.

=DLookUp("Fertigungsmenge";"Porduction Table";"Fertigungsmenge=200000")

This small command is also giving me a #error i want to know the exact syntax we use for forms in ms access.

thanks in advance.

Comment: if you have the source table open in design it cannot retrieve data so it gives the error. Close all related tables and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Table names, Field names that have **special characters** - yes that includes Spaces; should be enclosed in square brackets. So try.

```
= DLookUp("Fertigungsmenge";"[Porduction Table]";"Fertigungsmenge = 200000")
```

Also, the DLookup will fail if there is no value found for the criteria. It will return a Null instead. So it would be best you wrap the DLookup with a **Nz()** function.

Finally, the separator normally is a **comma** (',') a very few countries/regions have the semi-colon (';') as the separator. So give that one final check.

PS: To refer Forms and SubForm controls refer to this matrix : http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm

Comment: Thank you for your quick response paul as i satay in germany the semi-colon syntax is correct but i just want to say one thing iam not searching for a unique value the value i want to lookup is a sum and group by value does that make any difference in dlookup error ??

Comment: Should not, try the other two suggestions.

Comment: I tried but the same error message in the text box and the dlookup is not working properly. When i gave the dlookup it is giving the same error i tried in different ways but no positive output.

Comment: This is what i tried now  =Nz([Stuck]=DLookUp("[Sum of stuck]";"[query4subform]";"[query4 subform]![ET lot Nr]=[Delivery]![Lot Nr]"))

Comment: What is [Stuck]? Why is the Domain name different on the second argument and different on the criteria argument? What are you trying to do by using the bang (!) operator? You just need to use the Field Name. What is Delivery - SubForm? How is the subform hierarchically placed in the form? Finally I suggested to wrap the DLookup in Nz not the entire statement. Nothing wrong if you did, but Nz is mainly needed for DLookup.

Comment: Stuck is the name i gave for the lookup operation and i have my lookup value in query4subform so iam caling it from there and delivery is the second sub form i want to lookup the value from query4.subform to the delivery sub form by using the criteria of Lot Nr.

Comment: under artikel data main form there are two sub forms query4subform and delivery subform and i want to lookup the value from query4subform to the delivery subform.